# Specify target blob container for on-demand HDInsight action in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

When creating an HDInsight cluster in Azure it is possible to set a specific blob container inside the selected storage account, so it is possible to re-use the same container when creating a new cluster in a second moment.
When creating an on-demand cluster using the Data Factory's HDInsight action, I can only specify the storage account but not the blob container, so at every pipeline run a new container is generated.

Is there a way to avoid that behaviour and setting the container name for the on-demand HDInsght cluster?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, we cannot specify the container when creating the linked service. We can only specify the container when creating the dataset.
   [image]
2. Sharing one blob container as the default file system for multiple clusters isn't supported. You can refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage).

> Sharing one blob container as the default file system for multiple clusters isn't supported.